# DataTables multi select rows issue with button in table

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to use the multi select rows function of [DataTables](https://datatables.net), for now that make the job but when i add a `"defaultContent": "<button class='btn_planning'>Show</button>"` in my table there is a problem. That select the row when i click on button too :\

Live example :

[live.datatables.net](http://live.datatables.net/mirujexi/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to turn off the `selector` for the specific column holding a `<button>` :

```
select: {
  style: 'os',
  selector: 'td:not(:nth-child( COLUMN_INDEX ))' //dataTable column index + 1
}
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/f8ke0wwk/**